# Problem assigning group members membership types other than default

Tags: 7, organic-groups

core 7.29
og 7.x-2.x-dev, also tested 7x-2.7

So, I'm going a little crazy trying to get users assigned a membership type other than default in an og.

I can create a new membership type no problem, and add fields. What I can't do for the life of me is find how to assign users to that membership type. The [node 1 video](https://vimeo.com/32557401) made it seem like it shows automatically when adding/editing a user in a group (#overlay=group/node/1/admin/people/add-user), as roles do, but no dice. I realize that video is 2 years old, but it is the most helpful thing I can find on the subject.

Any thoughts/help?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the rules module to accomplish that. It's pretty powerful and if you haven't used it before make sure to add it to one if your most favorite modules list. Here's some good advice that'll get you going  https://forums.acquia.com/acquia-products-and-services/dev-desktop/auto-assign-og-groups-user-roles

Comment: Thanks @EmkoOne, unfortunately my issue is around membership types, and not roles. I need to use OG membership types in order to associate a few group specific fields to users. Thanks for the thought though!